# Java - summing list with filtering out lowest int

Tags: java, java-stream

So, I have an int[] arr and want to sum it using streams while filtering out the minimum int. 
I have got a solution using two streams, which works but seems ineffective. Is there a way to do it with just one stream?

Code:

```
int min = Arrays.stream(arr)
                    .min()
                    .getAsInt();
int sum = Arrays.stream(arr)
                       .filter(i -> i != min)
                       .sum();
```

Comment: One option (probably not the most efficient): `Arrays.stream(arr).sorted().skip(1).sum()`. May throw an exception for an empty array though.

Comment: this is helpful as I am assuming the array to be filled anyway, thanks.

Comment: Do you want to remove all instances of the smallest value or just one of them?

Comment: That is indeed a good question, in that case the approach in my comment won't suffice.

Comment: @rph that looks smaller in source code, but will be more expensive at runtime.

Comment: You could potentially do it yourself manually while iterating, so pretty much copying what `summaryStatistics()` does. Which would be something like `Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(v -> { sum += v; if (v < min) min = v; });` and then `sum -= min;`. You need a wrapper for `sum` and `min` though because of *effectively final*.

Comment: @Holger That's correct. That's why the comment mentions it's not the most efficient option. For efficiency, a traditional imperative loop will offer better results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int[] arr = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

int sumExcludingMin = Arrays.stream(arr)
            .sorted()
            .skip(1)
            .reduce(0, Integer::sum); // or using lambda: reduce(0, (x,y) -> x+y)
                                      // or specialized reduction form: sum()
```

Here, the first parameter of `reduce()`, `0`, the identity element is both an initial seed value for the reduction and a default result if there are no input elements.

**Further Reading:**

- Summary of [Package `java.util.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

Comment: There is no advantage in using `reduce(0, Integer::sum)` instead of `sum()`. Besides that unnecessary complication, it’s the same as posted in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62179095/62190448#comment109970451_62179095), so what has said there, applies to this answer as well. This is inefficient. It’s far worse than using two streams, as the `sorted` operation needs a temporary buffer of the same size as the original array. So you still have the costs of two iterations, one to fill the buffer and another processing the sorted result, *plus* the costs of sort operation.

Answer (score 5):

This code below using [IntSummaryStatistics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) should do the trick.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    IntSummaryStatistics stats = Arrays.stream(arr).summaryStatistics();
    int sum = (int) stats.getSum() - stats.getMin();
}
```

From docs of IntSummaryStatistics:

> A state object for collecting statistics such as count, min, max, sum, and average.
>
> ...
>
> This computes, in a single pass, the count of people, as well as the minimum, maximum, sum, and average of their number of dependents.

**EDIT:** In case you'd like to remove all elements which have min value:

```
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1};

    TreeMap<Integer, Integer> map = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed()
        .collect(toMap(
            v -> v,
            v -> 1,
            Integer::sum,
            TreeMap::new
        ));

    map.remove(map.firstKey());
    int sum = map.entrySet().stream().mapToInt(e -> e.getKey() * e.getValue()).sum();
    System.out.println(sum);
```

or

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(arr).sorted().boxed().collect(toList());
    Integer min = list.get(0);
    int sum2 = list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).dropWhile(min::equals).sum();
    System.out.println(sum2);
```

Comment: Indeed! One of the cleaner way to deal with it using a strictly single iteration of the array elements along with streams. But you might as well explain the code slightly more, possibly linking the Javadoc to `IntSummaryStatistics`.

Comment: This will not do the same in case of duplicates. However, it’s not clear whether the original code’s behavior truly is intended…

Answer (score 0):

Another trick : 
Don't use parallel stream. It will give wrong results . It will perform well .Its linear 0(n)

```
            int[] min=new int[1];
            min[0]=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int sum = Arrays.stream(arr).map(x->{min[0]=Math.min(x,min[0]); return x;}).sum();
            System.out.println(min[0]);
            System.out.println(sum-min[0]); // can overflow!
```

Comment: That’s an awful abuse of the API. But when you do it, just use `peek(x -> min[0]=Math.min(x,min[0]))` instead of using `map`. And for readability, consider removing unnecessary indention from the code .